# SQL Server - Copy database from Server 2008 to Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two servers one in Denmark the other here in the UK. I need to make a copy of a database out of SQL Server Management 2008 (1st server) and place it in SQL Server Management 2012(2nd server). I have tried connecting to the remote server but have been getting difficulties so instead of connecting both up and doing it that way I was hoping there is a function like copy database which could do this for me. I have gone into tasks and copy database in SQL Server 2008 but in the Copy Database Wizard that appears it says "You can use this wizard to move or copy databases from an instance of SQL Server 2000 or later to an instance of SQL Server 2008". I'm looking for something like this that will work for Server 2012.

Comment: Do you have RDP Access on 2008 server or not?

Comment: Yes I do sorry.

Comment: 2008 to 2012 fine, 2012 to 2008 not fine

Comment: Yes backwards doesn't work but forwards does so aslong as its the same or newer instance its fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy your database file `.mdf` and log file `.ldf` and paste in your SQL Server
2. Install file in `Programs Files->Microsoft SQL Server->MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS->MSSQL->DATA`.
3. Open SQL Server. Right-click on Databases then Select `Attach...` option.

Comment: For us this is the best way of doing it please note for future reference this method requires you to stop the SQL Server service whilst you copy the files from the location above. This means if it is a live database you need to plan a time to do it out of work hours.

Comment: Glad to help @Code Monster

Answer (score 0):

You can create a backup with the Management Studio on the source and restore it on the target.

Answer (score 0):

You need Management Studio 2012 to make this step. You can then create empty database on 2012 server. Right click on this empty **DB->Tasks->Copy database..**

Wizard will guide you. You should to this under 2012 Management Studio because it is compatible with 2008 Server - vice versa it will not work.

Of course, cleanest way is to do this via backup (**.bak** file - **Tasks->Backup..** then on 2012 server **Tasks->Restore->Files or FileGroups**) but you need remote access (RDP) to the server.